# Is the reciprocal of a function always another function? As opposed to a relation, or some other thing.

Tags: functions

> Is the reciprocal of a function always another function? As opposed to a relation, or some other thing.

Comment: If I have a function from the set $\{\text{apple},\text{banana},\text{chocolate}\}$ to $\{a,b,c\}$ which maps a word to the first letter of the word, so $f(\text{apple})=a$ for instance, what do you think $\frac{1}{f}(\text{apple})$ should be?  What is $1/a$?  It doesn't necessarily always make sense to talk about reciprocals of things.  Now... if you were talking about real functions, you again run into a challenge if any of the outputs were ever zero.  Consider the real function $f(x)=x$, but then $\frac{1}{f}(0) = \frac{1}{f(0)}=\frac{1}{0}$ which is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I will begin by reminding you what a function and a relation *is*.  A relation over sets $X$ and $Y$ (*where $X$ is called the domain and $Y$ the codomain*) is very simply a subset of $X\times Y$.  A function is a relation, though a very special kind of relation that satisfies some key properties.

Specifically for a relation $f$ to be a function we must have that for each element $x$ in the domain there is exactly one element $y$ in the codomain such that that $(x,y)$ is an element of the relation.  If $(x,y)$ is in the relation, we can write this as $f(x)=y$.

Finally, if we wish, we can write a function in the form $f(x)$ being set equal to some expression involving $x$, making sure to clarify what the domain and codomain of the function is as this is necessary to distinguish it from other similar but technically different functions.

---

Now, on to your question, given a function $f$ with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$, we can attempt to define the reciprocal function: $\frac{1}{f}$ as the set $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y~:~(x,\frac{1}{y})\in f\}$

As alluded to in my comments above however, this poses a problem in situations where reciprocals of certain elements in the codomain don't exist.  It doesn't make sense to talk about the reciprocal of "apple" just as it doesn't make sense to talk about the reciprocal of $0$.

In such an event that an element $y$ in the range of $f$ does not have its reciprocal defined or is otherwise not an element of the codomain, then we have the situation that $\frac{1}{f}$ of a preimage of $y$ is undefined, and so we will have an example of an $x$ in the domain such that there does *not* exist any $y$ in the codomain such that $(x,y)\in\frac{1}{f}$.

---

For example, the function $f$ with domain and codomain the real numbers given by $f(x)=x$, i.e. the function $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R\times \Bbb R~:~x=y\}$ will be such that $\frac{1}{f}$ is not a function over the real numbers since $\frac{1}{f}(0)=\frac{1}{f(0)}=\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined.  Yes, you can say it is a function over the domain of the *nonzero real numbers*, but that is changing the domain and as such changing the function.

Similarly, the function $f$ with domain and codomain the natural numbers given by $f(n)=n$ will be such that $\frac{1}{f} = \{(1,1)\}$ as the only natural number whose reciprocal is also a natural number is $1$.  Each of $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots$ are not natural numbers and so don't exist in the codomain and will not be included in the reciprocal relation.

On the other hand, the function $f$ with domain and codomain the natural numbers given by $f(n)=1$ will be a function as $\frac{1}{f}(n)=\frac{1}{f(n)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$ is well defined for every $n$.

---

In conclusion, the reciprocal of a function will always be a relation and might be a function assuming that the reciprocal of every element in the image exists and is also an element of the codomain.  For those functions which fail this condition, you may "restrict" the domain to a smaller domain, one such that the function is well defined for each, making it a function on this smaller domain.